Why would an advanced society settle most major political questions with games?
I want to make a society which settles most major political questions e.g. tax codes, war, foreign policy, etc with competitive games where different factions sponsor gamers to do games and where the best gamer wins the debate and gets whatever policy set up. There are special resources that mean that wealthier factions or factions with better access to rare resources have a competitive advantage in games that's greater than our earth, and watching and betting on such games would be routine.
Why would an advanced society use this system though, rather than a more normal system like democracy or a dictatorship or such?
A good answer will explain how a society would set up such a system to be politically stable and remain as the dominant method of solving political conflicts.

In real life, these games are called political campaigns, or, in those countries which consider themselves democracies, electoral campaigns. These are the most intricate, the most entertaining, the most expensive, and the most consequential games in our world. Watching those games and betting on their outcome is indeed routine. It seems to me that the question seems to be posed from a point of view where the actual time-tested complex political games are replaced with inferior and vastly less entertaining substitutes. Why replace a game which captures the attention of millions of people?

That is the worldbuilding question to answer. That said, I know say NFL is more popular than elections in terms of spending, getting around 18 billion compared to the 2020 presidential election just spending around 14 billion.

Yeah, but they spent 14 billion on one match. The National Collisionball League spent 18 billion on how many large number of matches they play in one year. If you want real numbers you need to add up all the money spent on all the political matches in an electoral cycle.

https://www.opensecrets.org/elections-overview/cost-of-election?cycle=2020&display=T&infl=N according to this, 14 billion was for both congress and presidential elections. So, a single sports outspent the elections. There are many sports. As such, while I am not required to adhere to realism based on earthly elections, i feel my question passes that bar.

When modern economies reach into old jungles, they often teach the people there games instead of fighting to kill each other. Keeping people alive is better for economies (see Gaza). Videos of former Papua New Guinea headhunters strutting as they win a point in a Cricket game are interesting to watch.

Iain M. Banks: The Player of Games is based on a comparable premise.

The Games are unique to each political problem and are a microcosm of the problem. The Games allow each side to try their respective solution in a controlled environment
And in some cases - we already do this. Think about Military Strategy - the Military regularly does 'War Games' to test out ideas/tactics etc.
The society realized - that Ideas, Debate and a such whilst helpful, pale in comparison to practical application.
(as a snide counter-argument to the above suggested political system - The society saw how certain theoretical political ideologies that promised Utopia, turned into utter hell-scapes when implemented)
And so with advances in both technology (some Games are best played on a Computer simulation, but with real players) and advances in things like Holographic technology - it allows the Political system to quickly and efficiently setup a game, with the 'rules' of the game based around the problem that is being attempted to be solved - then the players play to win.
Want to introduce a new tax? Setup a small scale game with 2 groups of 100 partipants, they are given initial starting funds - one group has the current tax system, the other has the new tax system - after X amount of time - the winner is the group that has generated the most additional resources.
Now - for Political Stability - there are three things IMO that you need for Political Stability:
1: Faith in the system. If you believe the system is fair, than you can accept a result you don't like. If you believe the system is rigged, than no result is acceptable.
2: Free from overreach. The less a Government interferes with your day-to-day life, the less irritation you are going to feel from the Government.
3: No dishonest actors trying to undermine the political process. This is perhaps the current problem in the west, among other things.
The faith in the system comes from the fact that the Games are broadcast, the rules are known, the sponsors/donors/lobbyists are known - and ultimately, whilst they can stack the deck as much as possible - time has shown that this has little effect in the long run.
Free from Overreach - in multiple games it shows that a system with more freedom and less rules always outcompetes a system that has excessive beaurocracy as the other side need to waste time and manpower enforcing rules that the other side doesn't need to.
Dishonest actors trying to undermine the system - you can make dishonest arguments and debates in public - but once their ideas enter the Game - they always loose.

This answer is pretty good as it gives a clear guide on how to manage the games and the system.

At the foundation of almost all of our decision-making and interactions lies "game theory". I think this concept definitely is worth exploring in the context of what you're asking about.
It's rules can be used to explain behavior as complex as international politics (possibly even interstellar, if you assume alien races that would follow logic sufficiently similar to ours),
or as simple as strategies employed in a board game.
You can say that our entires lives, as individuals and as a civilisation is just one, big, very, very complex game.
You could take a position questioning the necessity of complex management systems, criticising them as being too convoluted - difficult to predict and control, inefficient.
Instead, simple gaming disciplines could be better aimed at specific requirements, without undesired factors (inheritance, wealth, fame, manipulation, charisma, connections) becoming decisive for everything.
If you think about it, it -is- quite inefficient in our society.
For example:

ownership over mining company could be given to individual who can win a simplied game at collecting resources,
political position can be given to individual who excels at solving problems, which are predicted to appear in upcoming future.


Status-quo defense in a semi-communist society.
The Democratic People's Republic of Sportsland has

state ownership of all "productive" property - land, factories, laboratories, livestock, vehicles, radio towers, etc.
for ordinary individuals, private ownership of immediate personal property like toothbrushes, food, and clothing.
for Party members, also private ownership of other types of non-productive property, including recreational organizations.

Wealthy Party members as usual transfer the officially state-owned wealth that they control in trust to their own private property that is protected by the locked-in apparatus of the state, rather than perpetually in danger of being sent elsewhere by a vote of the politburo.
Since professional sports teams are de facto productive property that can make them more wealthy instead of just sequestering what they skim off of the state, sports teams are an excellent place to put your corrupt gains.
Reformers want to reclassify what counts as productive property, but the wealthy and powerful Party members all own sports teams already and don't want them redistributed. To ensure that they are hard to dislodge by a reform movement and cement their position of power, they use their current position of control of the politburo and change the laws so that you have to win various sporting events to pass legislation.
